# How to include dependencies with npm build

Tags: node.js, node-modules

How can I include runtime dependencies with "npm run build" ? Do I supposed to do that?

If not, what's the practice to run the build in another machine?

Comment: What do you mean by run-time dependencies ? Is that the packages with binary dpendencies ?

Comment: Yes, with binary dependencies